# AudioToolbox framework capabilities

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to know if AudioToolbox.framework will suppport an array of pageviewcontrollers to change with audio synchronization programmtically. From the apple documentation I found that Audio Queue Services lets you record, play, pause, loop, and synchronize audio but when they say synchronize audio are they referring to page change synchronization or something else?

I already have AVFoundation.framework in my app to play an audio file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a 'Core' AV library. You'll have to you your own program to interact with or manipulate your UI. The library does not rely on either AppKit or UIKit.

Sync: consider it along the lines of accurate timing of audio playback.